# Python/Cython/Numpy efficiently maintaining a list with max length

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, cython

I need some tips or solutions on how to maintain a list of objects (dicts or custom Python types through Cython) limited to a max length, effectively.

Basically doing this takes too much time:

```py
my_list = [a, b, c, d, ....]
my_list = my_list[-50:]
```

Is there any efficient way to make a list using Python, Cython (C/C++), Numpy that forgets the oldest item added to it above a threshold? For example beyond 50 items.

Comment: Do you need constant time random access?

Comment: Not completely familiar with the term "constant time random access", but i basically need the correct order they where added in. It is used to keep a history. (financial time series data). Unless it is faster to resort the returned list every time it is used.

Comment: Why was my question down voted? Please add an explenation when down voting so that people can improve the question or avoid making similar mistakes later on.

Comment: I hasn't down-voted.

Comment: Constant time random access means that you can get a value at any index in constant time, that is the time does not depend on the size of your container. Python's lists and nympy/C/C++ arrays have this property. If you are going to be traversing and indexing the structure a lot, you need this property.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @EliKorvigo :) Also the down vote question wasn’t directed at you, just wanted to know why i was down voted by whoever did it. I feel like the question was following all guidelines set by Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's collections module has the [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque) or "double-ended queue" which can be efficiently manipulated at either the beginning or end of the array. You can put a maximum size on one like so

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(maxlen=5)

d.extend(range(4)) # -> [0,1,2,3]    # before maxlen
d.append(4)        # -> [0,1,2,3,4]  # at max len
d.append(5)        # -> [1,2,3,4,5]  # drops first entry on appending beyond maxlen
```

Comment: This looks like what i needed :) Thank you!

Comment: I was going to recommend the same thing, that's why I asked the OP about access time complexity. I believe, you should pount out, that indexing queues is not efficient.

Comment: @EliKorvigo if you have an alternative solution with different properties feel free to post it! :)

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yup. OP, indexing queries are O(1) at the ends and O(n/2) in the middle. However, for a length 50 deque, I wouldn't worry about that. We're talking 2 -- 4 nanoseconds (5 -- 10%) difference on my system.

Comment: I've pointed that out, because, surely, 50 is just an example. Regarding alternative data structures, the OP might consider a fixed-size binary min-heap. Push and pop will cost O(log(n)), but so will random access. In other words, it all boils down to OP's use-case.